# How to join three tables for filteration?

Tags: magento-1.9, filter, join, join-table

I am applying filter on order collection. I am stuck in a situation, I have added a custom attribute to "customer address". that is in table "customer_address_entity_varchar", now I have to join following three tables, (1)sales_flat_order (2)sales_flat_order_address (3) customer_address_entity_varchar. In a such way as shown bellow, I know that is not right thing.

```
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
            //Filter for excluding Stores
        if (!empty($excludeStoresIds)) {
            $excludeStoresIds = explode(',', $excludeStoresIds);
            $excludeStoresIds = array_map('trim', $excludeStoresIds); //Remove white spaces
            $orderCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfoa' => 'sales_flat_order_address'), 'main_table.entity_id = sfoa.parent_id', "");
            $orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('sfoa.address_type', array('eq' => 'shipping'));
            $orderCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfoa' => 'sales_flat_order_address','caev' => 'customer_address_entity_varchar'), 'sfoa.customer_address_id = caev.entity_id', "");
            $orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('caev.value', array('nin' => $excludeStoresIds));
        }
```

Here **$excludeStoresIds** is an array

Comment: I tried [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32267279/magento-join-query-query-using-3-table), but not working

Comment: Well in your code above, there is an issue, you gave the same alias to `sales_flat_order_address`. Name the second one `sfoa2` for example, and try again. (you will need to change sfoa to sfoa2 in every reference in this join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Mayers

```
$orderCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfoa' => 'sales_flat_order_address'), 'main_table.entity_id = sfoa.parent_id', "");
            $orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('sfoa.address_type', array('eq' => 'shipping'));
            $orderCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('caev' => 'customer_address_entity_varchar'), 'caev.entity_id = sfoa.customer_address_id', "");
            $orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('caev.value', array('nin' => $excludeStoresIds));
```